# Proving a limit converges to an equation

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

Verify that $\lim{\epsilon→0}$ of the given equation converges to the equation of $y=xe^{px}$
$$y=\frac{-1}{\epsilon}e^{px}+\frac{1}{\epsilon}e^{(p+\epsilon)x}$$

After I finish my work, I ended up with the result of $\frac{-1}{\epsilon}e^{px}+\frac{1}{3}e^{px}$

Anyone have any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite it as 
$$\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\varepsilon} (e^{(p+\varepsilon )x} -e^{px}) = \frac{d}{dp} e^{px}=xe^{px}$$